# Euler #4 Largest Palindrome, python 2

Tags: python-2.7

I can't figure out why the list I try to generate of largest palindromes is incomplete. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
num1 = 999
num2 = 998
palinList = []

for num2 in range(num1,100,-1):
    product = num1 * num2
    if (str(product) != str(product)[::-1]):
        num1 = num1 - 1

    else:
        palinList.append(product)
        num1 = num1 - 1

palinList
```

yields:

```
[698896, 94249, 69696, 44944, 40804, 14641, 12321, 10201]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only multiplying from 999 - 100 like so

```
999 * 999
998 * 998
997 * 997
etc...
```

You need to have a nested loop so that you are multiplying all combination of 3 digit numbers, like the following:

```
palinList = []

for num1 in range(999,100,-1):
    for num2 in range(999,100,-1):

        product = num1 * num2
        if (str(product) == str(product)[::-1]):
            palinList.append(product)

palinList
```